# Append value to table by "reference"

Tags: lua, lua-table

I am trying to add a value to a table/array/list  (I am still not sure where the limits of those are in lua).

I know I can just do the following and it works

```
local argumentList = {};
table.insert(argumentList , 'hello I'm the first value0);
```

However is it possible to do the following?

```
local argumentList  = {};
argumentList:insert('hello I'm the first value0);
```

If possible without having to alter metatables 'cause I'm learning for making and addon for wow and it doesn't allow it. (Or better said I haven't been able to do it)

Comment: `local argumentList  = {insert=table.insert}; argumentList:insert('hello I\'m the first value');`

Comment: Thanks, this is what i was looking for, although for what I am currently using it it feels overkill.

Answer (score -1):

yes you can do that, however u need to use the colon `:`

```lua
argumentList:insert('hello I'm the first value0);
```

this is because with the colon, we indicate to Lua that the object is the `self`

```lua
class.method(self,params)
```

is equal to:

```lua
object:method(params)
```

in this case, `self` is already collecting `object` as a value, so it does not need to be passed as an argument

Comment: This only works if `argumentList` has an `insert` method though, that is, you need to `argumentList.insert = table.insert` before you can call it like that.